Is it possible to create a blendshape in Unity?
I have a character and I would like to add a simple blink animation to it. But the trouble is that the character doesn't have any bones controlling it's eyelids, and there are no existing blenshapes for blinking.
I can use the character mesh to create a blendshape with closed eyes via probuilder but the trouble is how can I then apply this to the character?

I don't believe this is supported natively, but you could probably write an editor script that reads your modified mesh and converts it into a blend shape to save into the source mesh.
